# How to force page numbering in a given page

Tags: page-numbering

I am using a Thesis document class. There are pages that come out without a number. For example, the first page of the Table of Contents has no number, although I now it is being counted, because the next page (i.e., the second page of the Table of Contents) has a number, and it is one more than the one that is absent from the previous page.

How can I **force** LaTeX to display a number in every page?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also note that some classes/styles provide move the page number to the bottom or omit it if it's the first page of a chapter, and some templates also remove the number completely on an empty page between chapters. Both is considered typographically correct.

Comment: Hi yo, I think it has to do with what you mention, as the page numbers are removed from every first chapter including the front matter. Is there a way to overrule that first-page-of-chapter page numbering removal? Thanks

Comment: @Elsarcas: This may be as easy as adding `\makeatletter\let\ps@oldempty\ps@empty\let\ps@empty\ps@plain\makeatletter` in your preamble if all pages that don't have a page number uses the `empty` page style and those that do use `plain`. The first `\let` saves the `empty` page style in `oldempty`, so if you need it (perhaps for the title page), you can still issue `\thispagestyle{oldempty}`.